# Oracle 2 Indexes on same columns but different order

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-performance, query-performance

I have a table in production environment that has 2 Indexes on a Table with the same columns in the Index but in reversed order.

DDL is

```
 - CREATE INDEX IND_1 ON ORDERS (STORE_ID,DIST_ID)  
 - CREATE INDEX IND_DL_1 ON ORDERS (DIST_ID,STORE_ID)
```

Are these two indexes not essentially the same. Why would someone create indexes such a way? Does reversing or changing of column position do something internally?

Comment: The rule of thumb for the order of columns in an index is that you want to **reduce the size of the sub tree** (meaning, the second level and on) ! so you want to put the value with the most distinct value's first.

Comment: These indexes look like perfect candidates for [index compression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5012.htm#BABHDBHE).

Comment: @haki That's not how B-Trees work. You won't actually reduce the number of nodes if you put more selective column first in the composite index. There is no "B-Tree level for first column" on top, "level for second column" beneath etc... In fact, putting less selective column first can help with Oracle index compression and may physically order the index in a more favorable way (depending on how you want to query). To quote Tom Kyte: _"It has not been true since at least version 6 that having the most selective first is better."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indexes are tied to the fields they're indexing, in the order they're being defined in the index. As long as you use the fields in the index, in their left->right order, then index is useable for your query. If you're skipping fields, then the index cannot be used. e.g. given the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ind1 ON foo (bar, baz, qux)
```

then these where clauses will be able to use the index:

```
WHERE bar=1
WHERE bar=1 AND baz=2
WHERE baz=2 AND bar=1  <--same as before
WHERE bar=1 AND baz=2 AND qux=3
```

The order you use the indexed fields in the query is not relevant, just that you ARE using them. However, the order they're defined in the index is critical. The following clauses can NOT use the index:

```
WHERE baz=2  <-- 'bar' not being used
WHERE baz=2 AND qux=3  <-- 'bar' again not being used
WHERE bar=1 AND qux=3  <-- the index can be partially used to find `bar`, but not qux.
```

For your two cases, there's nothing really wrong with how they're indexed, but it'd be slightly more efficient to index as follows:

```
(STORE_ID, DIST_ID)
(DIST_ID)
```

There's no point in indexing store_id in the second index, because the DBMS can use the first index to handle the store_id lookups. It's not a major gain, but still... maintaining indexes is overhead for the DB, and reducing overhead is always a good thing.

Comment: +1 - You're ignoring index skip scans, though.  Your second set of clauses could use the index.  But it would have to be a less efficient skip scan (particularly as the number of distinct values in the leading column increases) rather than a more efficient range scan.

Comment: Also, the last statement isn't quite correct.  The `(store_id, dist_id)` index would not be the most efficient for a query like `dist_id = xxx and store_id < 10`.  On the other hand, this is find for `dist_id, store_id`.

Comment: *"reducing overhead is always a good thing"* - except when the extra overhead saved *here* causes poor performance over *there*.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Now the concept is more clear to me.

Comment: _"There's no point in indexing store_id in the second index"_ - Except to [cover](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) a query.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not have to touch table segments in cases when all the needed information is found in indexes.
In your case these indexes can serve as a quick lookup/translation table STORE_ID => DIST_ID and vice-versa.

Just look at the exec plan for the query where you select only select STORE_ID based on DIST_ID,
the query will only go through index, and will not touch the table itself.

But maybe the reason is different (if any).